# cuSPARSE csrmm with dense matrix in row-major format

Tags: cuda, blas, sparse-matrix

I want to use the `cuSPARSE csrmm` function to multiply two matrices. The A matrix is sparse and the B matrix is dense. The dense matrix is in row-major format. Is there some nice way (trick) to accomplish this without the need to explicitly transpose B? I am thinking of something similar to [this](http://www.christophlassner.de/using-blas-from-c-with-row-major-data.html) for dense BLAS.

Thanks

Comment: the [csrmm2 function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrmm2) allows you to specify an optional transpose for the dense matrix.